# How to locally notify in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications, local, apple-push-notifications

I want to notify the user about something after some specific time. Are there any resources on this topic? Guides or sample code are particularly helpful. I have read a number of sites about it, but they are all about server side notifications like Facebook notify where if a message arrives or something like that. I just want it triggered locally from the iPhone app with no server involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep!  You're looking for a [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Once you've created one and configured it, you can either [present it immediately](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW87) or [schedule it to appear](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification%3a) at a certain point in time.

---

In other words:

```
//create the notification
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
//configure it (this sets the message to be displayed)
[notification setAlertBody:@"This is my local notification!"];
//the notification will show up in 60 seconds
[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60]];

//queue up the notification
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
//release the object we no longer care about
[notification release];
```

That's all there is to it, really.